# Reading the data from file and plotting fft

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I want to read data from the file and plot the fft of it.

I have used the scipy's fft function to plot the fft of the synthetically generated signal data however while I am trying to save the generated signal data and plot the fft I am getting the peaks as I was getting but the value of the amplitude and frequency is off as compared to the Original plotting.I found problem with the second fft function. Can anyone help me with the  same.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy.fftpack import fft,fftfreq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

#Function to plot the raw data
def raw_plot(signals,time):
    '''Plot the raw values in the time domain '''
    plt.figure(0)
    plt.plot(time,signals)
    plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
    plt.ylabel("Amplitude(g)")
    plt.show()
#Function to plot the fft of the data
def fft_signal(signal, sampling_frequency, timestart, timeend):
        T = 1 / sampling_frequency
        N = (timeend - timestart) * sampling_frequency  
        x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * T), int(N / 2))
        # print("Values of X are :",x)
        # print(len(x))
        yr2 = fft(signal)
        y2 = 2 / N * np.abs(yr2[0:int(N / 2)])
        #         amp_spec = abs(fft(signal))/N
        #         freq = np.linspace(0,2,num=N)
        plt.figure(2)
        plt.plot(x, y2)
        plt.xlabel("Frequency")
        plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
        plt.show()


def fftsignal2(data, sampling_freq = 100, timestep = 1 ):

    N = len(data)
    FS = 1000
    T= 1/FS
    timestep = timestep
    yr2 = fft(data)
    y2 = 2 / N * np.abs(yr2[0:int(N / 2)])
    # f= np.arange(0,N)*FS/N
    # f= np.linspace(0,1.0/T,N)
    frq = np.fft.fftfreq(N,d=timestep)
    # f= np.linspace(0.0,int(N/2)*sampling_freq)
    frq= frq[0:len(frq)//2]
    print("Frequencies Length :",len(frq))
    print("DATA LENGTH :",len(y2))
    plt.figure(3)
    plt.plot(frq,y2)
    plt.xlabel("Frequency")
    plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    plt.show()



Mag1_Hz = 70
Mag1_AMP = 10

Mag4_AMP = 60
Mag4_Hz= 50


Mag2_Hz = 20
Mag2_AMP = 8

time_start = 0
time_end = 4
Sampling_frequency = 100 
No_of_samples  = (time_end-time_start) * Sampling_frequency

time = np.linspace(time_start,time_end,No_of_samples)

#Generate the signals values

data_signal = Mag1_AMP * np.sin(2* np.pi * Mag1_Hz * time ) + Mag2_AMP * np.cos(2* np.pi * Mag2_Hz * time)

raw_plot(signals=data_signal[:800],time=time[:800])
fft_signal(data_signal,sampling_frequency=Sampling_frequency,timestart=time_start,timeend=time_end)

# for (time, datavalues) in zip(time,data_signal):
#     with open("data_signals_27.csv","a",newline="") as file:
#         writefile = csv.writer(file)
#         print("Time%f,Data %f"%(time,datavalues))
#         print(time,datavalues)
#         writefile.writerow([time,datavalues])



fftsignal2(data= data_signal, sampling_freq= Sampling_frequency,timestep=2)
```

The peaks are coming right in the fft_signal function no 1 while I am trying to construct the fftsignal2 to plot the fft of the data so the peaks which I am getting is correct but the magnitude and frequency is off.I don't understand why ? Can anyone help me with that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If the sampling frequency is 100Hz, the time step is 0.01s. Hence, the arguments `sampling_freq = 100, timestep = 1` of `fftsignal2()` are redundant and their default values are not consistent with one another. Could you try `np.fft.fftfreq(N,d=1.0/sampling_freq)`? Watch for integer divisions `FS = 1000   T= 1/FS` (ok if python 3). If the length of the frame is not a multiple of the period of the signal, or if your input signal is not periodic, you we be interested by applying a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) prior to DFT.

Comment: Hi, @francis Thanks for helping me out. It worked for me. However I am facing one other issue that while plotting the data the speed is very slow and the changes in the data is visible after  10 -15 seconds(on an average). How to speed up the same. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Redrawing a matplotlib plot is usualy quite fast (use [this code](https://block.arch.ethz.ch/blog/2016/08/dynamic-plotting-with-matplotlib/) for instance. And computing the DFT of a signal of length 800 is done in no time. You could profile your code using commands like `time.time()`, to investigate what operation takes time. If reading the file takes time (it would be surprising), you may try another library, one of those listed in [here](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/)